# numerical computation problems in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical, floating-point-precision

in this question i am addressing to  numerical computation problems in matlab and want to get experience how to avoid this problems/errors in future

for example let consider following  simple codes

```
t = 0.4 + 0.1 - 0.5

t =

     0
```

it works fine,but

```
u = 0.4 - 0.5 + 0.1

u =

   2.7756e-17
```

of course in  mind  it is also  0,but why not in first   calculation got the same result?or what is difference?also please look

```
v = (sin(2*pi) = = sin(4*pi)) 

v = (sin(2*pi)==sin(4*pi))

v =

     0
```

it shows that sine function is not periodic,so what is general advice  in this case?introduce some epsilon?like

```
V=((sin(2*pi)-sin(4*pi))<eps)

V =

     0
```

or

```
EPS=0.000000000000001

EPS =

   1.0000e-15

>> V=((sin(2*pi)-sin(4*pi))<EPS)

V =

     1
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal you get these results, because floating-point relative accuracy in Matlab is

```
eps('double')

ans =

   2.2204e-16
```

---

For `V=((sin(2*pi)-sin(4*pi))<eps)`, because

```
sin(2*pi)-sin(4*pi)

ans =

   2.4493e-16
```

which is larger than `eps('double')`, so its result will be `V=0`.

---

And for `V=((sin(2*pi)-sin(4*pi))<EPS)`, because `EPS>2.4493e-16`, so its result will be `V=1`.

Comment: so does it means that i have choose epsilon according my will?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Yes, you have to sometimes according how accurate you want it to be.

Comment: thanks very much ones again,in this case i will always choose  0.000000000000001  something like this :D